# Layout Method in qiskit

Tags: qiskit, optimization

Using `transpile` with `optimization_level = 3`, which is the layout method used by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DenseLayout` is used by default. You can see the code for the optimization level [here](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-terra/blob/master/qiskit/transpiler/preset_passmanagers/level3.py) and it is [this line](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-terra/blob/d5e0750d6fe0cae0a204a3cdd8751c0ede9ed6e1/qiskit/transpiler/preset_passmanagers/level3.py#L84) that sets the default to be the dense layout.

Comment: Thank you very much. But in your opinion using as layout method noise_adaptive give best perfomances ? I'm tring to understand which layout method allows to have the best performances

Comment: If you are going to be running it on the hardware it might be worth trying `NoiseAdaptive` too, it may be better but the only way to know for sure it to experiment! :) if this answer answered your question would you mind marking it as accepted?

Comment: Thanks again. Just another question: for what you know there is a way to check which layout is better whitout execute the jobs ? Maybe using simulations o something like that ?

Comment: You could try using a simulator with a `NoiseModel` corresponding to the device you eventually want to run the circuit on

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a `layout_method=...` arg to set this yourself. It currently accepts `'dense'`, `'noise_adaptive'` and `'trivial'`.

(There is a also an option for `routing_method=...` which accepts `'basic'`, `'stochastic'` and `'lookahead'`.)

The difference between the various levels (0,1,2,3) is then what parameters these passes run with. At higher level, they run with more time-consuming parameters which will probably yield better results. For example the number of trials is higher, or the lookahead window is larger.

Comment: Thanks. I ask you the same question I asked to met927: for what you know there is a way to check which layout is better whitout execute the jobs ? Maybe using simulations o something like that ?

Comment: Yes you can simulate it using a noise model based on that device's parameters. There's a tutorial on that here: https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-tutorials/blob/master/tutorials/simulators/2_device_noise_simulation.ipynb